# Does Black have a win in this position?

Tags: analysis

I was playing a game as Black against computer and came up a tactical move that defends me from pressure. I have expected a normal retreat of the queen yet computer kept sacrificing the knight like it was lost anyway, therefore this question :

Did I miss a win for Black or the position is just fine for White?

Here is the position:

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "4r1k1/3q1ppp/pp6/2QN1n2/1P6/8/P4PPP/3R2K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

*White kept playing `Nf6+` or `Qxb6` but I believe that any retreat of the queen is fine, what did I miss?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suspicion is that the computer is calculating at a depth of 3-ply. At 3-ply depth, it sees that the following variations are winning -

`1. Nf6+ gxf6 2. Rxd7` and

`1. Qxb6 Qxd5 2. Rxd5`

winning material.

If it was at 4-ply or more, it would have seen `2...Re1#` in both lines and rejected those lines.

To answer your question, no, Black doesn't have a win in this position. White can play `1. Qc1` and white is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Black has no win.  White scoops up the `b6` pawn and enjoys the advantage.

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "4r1k1/3q1ppp/pp6/2QN1n2/1P6/8/P4PPP/3R2K1 w - - 0 1"] 


     1.Qc1 Qa4 2.a3 Ne7 3.Nxb6 Qb5 4.Nc4 Nf5 5.g3 h6 6.Nd6 Nxd6 7.Rxd6 a5 8.bxa5 Qxa5 9.Qc6 Qa8 10.a4 Kf8 11.Kg2 Qxc6+ 12.Rxc6 Ra8 13.Rc4 Ke7 14.Kf3 Kd6 15.Rd4+ Kc6 16.h4 g6 17.Rf4 Ra7 18.Ke3 Kd5 19.Kd3 Ke5 20.Rb4
```

So says Stockfish 5.  Everything past move 5 or so is probably suspect but you get the idea.